# Wide Transformation in Spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark

Why Spark creates multiple stages for wide transformation even if data is present in one partition?

```
val a = sc.parallelize(Array("This","is","a","This","is","file"),1)
val b = a.map(x => (x,1))
val c = b.reduceByKey(_+_)
c.collect
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt that Spark is taking into account the fact that data is in only one partition. You have to take into account that Spark was designed with large scale processes in mind, so it may not be a priority to put in place an optimisation to prevent shuffling when there is only one partition.